# How can I just run a mywebsite/index.php file without Aptana calling remote debugger?

Tags: php, debugging, configuration, aptana

I was expecting, as is the case with Eclipse, that when I run code from the ide, that execution runs until user entry. I shouldn't see debugging occur when I "Run".

With Aptana, when I Run the localhost/index.php file, an annoying remote debug request is called and asks if I want to break on the first line. Often several threads are generated and I'm thrown into a debug perspective. ... despite having set "Never" in Preferences/Run-Debug/"launch in debug mode when workspace contains breakpoints".  This seems to only happen with .php files (html files run without debug being called).

"Run Configurations" and "Debug Configurations" appear to be the place to have run and debug operate differently, but they both have Debug options only. e.g. Run Configurations/PHP Web Page/Server  -> why does it ask for server debugger? I expect to see this only in "Debug Configurations"

Answer (score 0):

**If someone have better solution, Please share.**

I had to do a dirty workaround to get rid of the annoying "Path Mapping" from Aptana. I renamed my project's "index.php" to something else and it worked fine. I also added my index_page setting to new url so that it will not affect my project.

This is obviously a noob solution but i cant seem to find any better way to get rid of this.

Comment: I have started using Visual Studio code for PHP. Though it doesnt support lot of commercial PHP IDE's features, its debugging setup way more easier.